# How to complie C++ program on Google Compute Engine

Tags: c++, compilation, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I tried compiling C++ code on VM instance in Google Compute Engine

g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o output

It says 
bash: g++: command not found

I am not able to find any correct resource for this issue.

Comment: You probably want to start with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`, assuming a Debian-derivative system.  Not really related to the specific cloud platform though...

Answer (score 1):

"sudo apt-get install build-essential" will install latest version of c++ on your gcloud. One more modification I would do is  "g++ test.cpp -o output" would be good for running. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: My bad "sudo apt-get install build-essential". I just tried it worked